# include c/c++ unmanaged code dll, consumed using dllimport, in azure functions publish process

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, dllimport

How does one include in a c/c++ unmanaged code dll, consumed using v2 .net core compatible DllImportAttribute statements, in azure functions publish process?

I've confirmed it works in cloud deployment by manually copying, via azure storage explorer, to functions app storage account | file shares |  | site/wwwroot/bin folder.

Issue is now I haven't been able to find way to have it included in vs17 |  | Publish process.

Tried placing dll in \bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp2.1\bin folder before executing vs17 |  | Publish but doesn't result in it being picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS, right click on your Function project and `Edit <FunctionProjectName>.csproj`. Add items below to copy dlls we need when publishing or debugging locally.

```
  <!-- For publish -->
  <ItemGroup> 
    <None Include=" relative or absolute path to your dll, which is not in your project">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- If you have put dlls under your project root -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="YourDllName.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- For local debug -->
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="relative or absolute path to your dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build"><Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\Dll1\bin\Win32\$(Configuration)\Dll1.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" /> </Target> for local debug and that worked.

Comment: . . . and i tried <ItemGroup><None Include="d:\src\repos\MySolution\Dll1\bin\Win32\Release\Dll1.dll"><CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory></None></ItemGroup> for absolute path based inclusion in publish [ & pack ] output and that worked

Comment: . . . but when I tried the more desirable <ItemGroup><None Update="$(ProjectDir)..\Dll1\bin\Win32\$(Configuration)\Dll1.dll"><CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory></None></ItemGroup> for relative path based inclusion in publish [ & pack ] output that did not work, any thoughts as to why?

Comment: . . . and I think unrelated but i'm getting "An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin' & The error code was 0x800703E6." when trying to publish profile using MSDeploy vs ZipDeploy. Reason for wanting to exercise this publish option is to determine if it has any impact on vs17 | cloudexp | <func app> | attach debugger being able to successfully light up ide breakpoints [ https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3810 ].

Comment: ***status update***  the use of a relative path do dll worked for ItemGroup/None entry to include dll in publish output if I changed from <None Update=. . .> to <None Include=. . . > similar to what was used for the absolute path case.

Comment: @myusrn Ok, let's conquer these troubles one by one. 1. As mentioned in my post,  `<None Update= >` requires the dlls being put directly under your function project so it can find them as expected.

Comment: Thanks for additional insights.  I tried using `<None Update="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Dll1.dll">` and `<None Update="DllImport\Dll1.dll">` and neither led to Dll1.dll showing up in `$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp2.1\publish\bin` folder when I used <function project> | Pack or in `$(ProjectDir)\obj\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\bin` when I used <function project> | Publish. Not a problem i think at this point given `<None Insert=<relative path including macros>` works right?

Comment: @myusrn Sorry, that is my fault, actually we need to put dlls under project root to use `<None Update="Dll1.dll">`, no folder or relative path is acceptable, as we can see the folder structure will be generated in publish folder hence the dll can't be moved to `bin` as expected. And yes, `Include` item is useful as long as the dll is not located at current function project.(Insert should be a typo I assume).

Comment: @myusrn As for the publishing error, try to find `EnableMsDeployAppOffline` in publish profile and set `true`, it will stop your function app during deployment and start it later.

Comment: @myusrn I met the problem about attaching debugger as well, don't find a solution but I should say it has nothing to do with the publishing error.

Comment: \@jerry liu, thanks for suggestion on other error arising using MSDeploy vs ZipDeploy publish setting.  Tried with EnableMsDeployAppOffline set to True and got same result.  Its encouraging to hear you are having same issue with attaching debugger, suggesting i'm not having a workstation/project specific issue.  Note that I opened a functions repo issue to escalate that matter here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3810, which perhaps would get some more traction from a "happening to me to" comment.

Comment: . . . unrelated to the original issue but rather a SO comments nubie issue, i'm wondering why when I at sign reference your username in comment it hides that in comment displayed unless I prefixed it with backslash?

Comment: @myusrn Because we are discussing under my post(answer), so I(i.e the author) will get the prompt automatically hence you don't need at signing me manually, SO removes the extra info automatically. I need at signing you or you won't get prompt in messages box as there could be more than one people talking to the author.

Comment: Thanks for explanation that helps.  Btw I tested these same settings in azure web app csproj file and they worked there as well which is great cause I have to achieve the same thing in that project environment also.  On related front you might have insights on this new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688014/function-app-equivalent-for-ihostingenvironment-isdevelopment .

Comment: **status update** I found with additional functions v2 project testing, and unexpected results, that CopyToBin/Copy SourceFiles= drop in $(OutputDir)\bin was not being used and Update/CopyToOutputDirectory [ == $(OutputDir) ] was.  I determined this because I was using this for a native code dll accessed using dllimport so I could tell which file it was using for localhost build/rebuild debugging passes based on whether it failed when the file was x64 bit output vs the x86 bit [ / Win32 ] output that matched the process type localhost func.exe process executes under.