# function app equivalent for IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()

Tags: authentication, azure-functions

In asp.net core Startup.cs Configure we are provided an IHostingEnvironment env parameter that exposes an env.IsDevelopment() call to determine if you are currently running in a visual studio f5 debug session or a cloud deployment scenario.  In function app is there a story for determining this same thing so you can write code that only runs during f5 debug session, e.g. a populated (. . ., ClaimsPrincipal principal) dependency injected parameter where this is only normally assigned claims and roles when deployed into cloud EasyAuth enabled environment.

Answer (score 13):

`IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` actually checks whether the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable is set to "Development". If that's what you want to do then you can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` to check the value. However, to determine specifically if you're in an F5 debug session you should check `Debugger.IsAttached` instead.

Comment: Thanks for response and insights.  Would you expect Debugger.IsAttached to also return true in case where you have deployed function app in cloud and have used cloud explorer | {subscription} | app services | {function app} | attach debugger to carry out cloud deployment remotely debug session?  I'd test to see if that is the case for myself but currently that functionality is not working for me as detailed in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3810 .

Comment: Debugger.IsAttached doesn't discriminate between local and remote debuggers as far as I know.

Comment: The answer above gives you a solution. This is something that will also be made a bit simpler by some DI work for Azure Functions that is currently in progress. I'm following up on the other issue you've linked to, but that's unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I looks for the variable: FUNCTIONS_CORETOOLS_ENVIRONMENT